# RTMP Session.cpp file did not created create stream . I am getting error release stream?

Tags: ios, vlc, rtmp, red5, videocore

I'm using video core 0.1.12. And getting error at release stream. It's did not created stream  in RTMP session.cpp file. How to resolve it ?? help me anyone .